# Google Customer Reviews 1.7.5

Tags: prestashop

I need to add the code snippet to the order confirmation page for Google Customer Reviews.
Could you please tell me where I can find the order confirmation page and how to add the code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The page to modify in your theme folder is :

order-confirmation.tpl

If you do not have all variables needed by Google Customer reviews, my advice is to use a module.

**there is a free module :**

https://github.com/albangonzalez/googlecustomerreviewssnippet

**there is an paid module with more features :**

https://addons.prestashop.com/fr/seo-referencement-naturel/32364-google-customer-reviews-integration.html?_ga=2.60180719.370609758.1573549295-168217515.1541430234

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried to download the free module you linked but it gives me error. I have PS 1.7.5